# How to escape caret symbol in ZPL2

Tags: printing, label, escaping, zebra-printers

Does anybody know how to escape the caret symbol (^), which ZPL2 / zebra printers recognize as a control character for commands, to print this character as a text onto the zpl2 label?

Maybe I'm blind, but I could not find this info in the official zpl2 programming guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Field Hex command. ^FH

^XA
^FO100,100
^AD^FH
^FDCaret _5E^FS
^XZ

Answer lifted from the ZPL guide page 186:

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11420295)

Comment: @ndn Undoubtedly, it is very (too?) short, but are you certain that this is not the correct, or at least a possible, answer?

Comment: yes - it was one of those days that I saw the question - knew the answer but did not have the time to go into detail. The answer would be obvious if you looked up that command in the ZPL programming guide that was referenced in the question.